# Pod CocoaPods dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_GSDK_GTMSessionFetcher in iOS 8.0

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, unity-game-engine

I'm been struggling with a cocoaPods issue. I'm using Unity and XCode 7.3 + cocoaPods for Google Play sdk.

I spent the first day succeeding on building the project on iOS, but at runtime I'm getting a crash on device, just at startup.
[please note the referenced libs and the runtime error in the br corner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBWal.png)
On sim, same thing and the error is:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_GSDK_GTMSessionFetcher
```

Now, I see that GTMSessionFetcher is pulled in by Pod and essentially results in libGTMSessionFetcher.a, but it seems this library is not brought into the package at all, and I can't find a good way to do it. I added it in the project resources tree, in the linked libs and so on, but nothing really seems to solve my issue.

Comment: Hey, any luck with this? I've struggled for two weeks with this pain of an issue.

Comment: Even updating XCode to ver. 8, cocoapods etc, Google Play Services for Unity seems not to work fairy on iOS. It throws a lot of linking errors and even when you succeed in a build the app will crash instantiating the library.

Comment: Have you tried asking for help on Unity Answers? I watched a few videos on YouTube. They, and fresh documentation suggest that we use the `.xcodeproj` file to run the project. I asked a [question](http://answers.unity3d.com/comments/1286048/view.html) similar to this on Unity Answers.